# Use ellipsis in tweet via URI code in URL?

Tags: javascript, twitter

Working with some science journals to tweet articles, but many titles are too long so we're truncating them with an ellipsis. Problem is, via the tweet?text= method, the ellipsis comes out as a bad character. I use %23 to get around this for hashtags, is there something similar I can use in this instance?

ex:

"Bacterial Community Composition and Ext…" (2013) http://dx.doi.org/10.137/journal.pone.0083365

Comment: `%E2%80%A6` should work as an URL-encoded ellipsis in UTF-8 character encoding …

Comment: Whoa, let’s keep this strictly professional, hmkay? :-) Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%E2%80%A6` should work as an URL-encoded ellipsis in UTF-8 character encoding …